# for loop Multiprocessing or Multithreading in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, for-loop, multiprocessing

I have the following three for loop (two of them are nested) in python. The API requests should be sent concurrently. How to parallelized the execution?

```
args = []
args.extend((n, m) for n in (1,) for m in range(1, 4))
args.extend((n, m) for n in range(2, 5) for m in range(2, 5))
args.extend((n, m) for n in range(5, 14) for m in range(1, 5))

pool = ThreadPool(len(args))
# list of packets_received:
results = pool.starmap(my_function, args)
for result in results:
    # unpack the result tuple:
    packets_recieved,packets_transmitted,bytes_recieved,bytes_transmitted=result

#for sw1
for m in range (1,4,1):         
     print(packets_recieved,packets_transmitted,bytes_recieved,bytes_transmitted)
                                    
#for sw2,sw3,sw4
for n in range (2,5,1):
    for m in range (2,5,1):
            print(packets_recieved,packets_transmitted,bytes_recieved,bytes_transmitted)                           
#for sw5 to sw13
for n in range (5,14,1):
    for m in range (1,5,1):
        print(packets_recieved,packets_transmitted,bytes_recieved,bytes_transmitted)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Multithread functions in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36515270/how-to-multithread-functions-in-python)

Comment: @BakhoucheAkram That is really *not* the best approach. The answer you point to shows no way of returning a value back from the thread, which the OP clearly needs. The OP also has 48 threads they need to create. Would this be the best way or perhaps a thread pool, which also provides for the returning of results?

Comment: Okay,  thank you for the informatin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the three instances of `apiString` and rewriting them to use the more succinct *F-strings*, they all appear to be of the form:

```py
apiString = f'http://192.168.74.134:8181/restconf/operational/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/node/openflow:{n}/node-connector/openflow:{n}:{m}'
```

Even the first loop fits this format if `n` is 1 and `m` takes on values 1, 2, 3 and 4. So let's modify `my_function` to take two arguments, *n* and *m*:

```py
def my_function(n, m):
     apiString = f'http://192.168.74.134:8181/restconf/operational/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/node/openflow:{n}/node-connector/openflow:{n}:{m}'
    ... # //etc.
    return packets_recieved, packets_transmitted, bytes_recieved, bytes_transmitted
```

Now we just have to arrange to call this concurrently with the following (n, m) argument pairs, specified here as tuples (for the time being):

```py
args = []
args.extend((n, m) for n in (1,) for m in range(1, 4))
args.extend((n, m) for n in range(2, 5) for m in range(2, 5))
args.extend((n, m) for n in range(5, 14) for m in range(1, 5))
```

And putting it all together:

```py
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def my_function(n, m):
    apiString = f'http://192.168.74.134:8181/restconf/operational/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/node/openflow:{n}/node-connector/openflow:{n}:{m}'
    ... # //etc.
    return packets_recieved, packets_transmitted, bytes_recieved, bytes_transmitted

args = []
args.extend((n, m) for n in (1,) for m in range(1, 4))
args.extend((n, m) for n in range(2, 5) for m in range(2, 5))
args.extend((n, m) for n in range(5, 14) for m in range(1, 5))

# Creating thread pool whose size is the number of requests we need to make:
# (but it could be smaller, for example 10, if you wanted less concurrency):
pool = ThreadPool(len(args))
# list of packets_received:
results = pool.starmap(my_function, args)
for result in results:
    # unpack the result tuple:
    packets_recieved, packets_transmitted, bytes_recieved, bytes_transmitted = result
    print(packets_recieved, packets_transmitted, bytes_recieved, bytes_transmitted)
```

Method `starmap` will unpack each tuple in `args` and pass the elements of the tuple as individual arguments to `my_function`.

**Update**

I offer 3 ways of processing the `results` returned by the call to `starmap`. Chose one of these methods (but not all):

```py
# Option 1: Retrieve and print all N results corresponding to the N arguments in args
for result in results:
    # unpack the result tuple:
    packets_recieved, packets_transmitted, bytes_recieved, bytes_transmitted = result
    print(packets_recieved, packets_transmitted, bytes_recieved, bytes_transmitted)
    
# Option 2: Retrieve and print all N results in 3 separate loops:
it = iter(results) # create an iterator for results
for n in (1,):
    for m in range(1, 4):
        result = next(it) # get next result
    # unpack the result tuple:
    packets_recieved, packets_transmitted, bytes_recieved, bytes_transmitted = result
    # you can now also print the n and m value:
    print(n, m, packets_recieved, packets_transmitted, bytes_recieved, bytes_transmitted)
for n in (2, 5):
    for m in range(2, 5):
        result = next(it) # get next result
    # unpack the result tuple:
    packets_recieved, packets_transmitted, bytes_recieved, bytes_transmitted = result
    # you can now also print the n and m values:
    print(n, m, packets_recieved, packets_transmitted, bytes_recieved, bytes_transmitted)
for n in (5, 14):
    for m in range(1, 5):
        result = next(it) # get next result
    # unpack the result tuple:
    packets_recieved, packets_transmitted, bytes_recieved, bytes_transmitted = result
    # you can now also print the n and m value:
    print(n, m, packets_recieved, packets_transmitted, bytes_recieved, bytes_transmitted)

# Option 3: Using enumerate:
for idx, result in enumerate(results):
    arg = args[idx]
    # unpack the arg tuplet
    n, m = arg
    # unpack the result tuple:
    packets_recieved, packets_transmitted, bytes_recieved, bytes_transmitted = result
    # you can now also print the n and m values:
    print(n, m, packets_recieved, packets_transmitted, bytes_recieved, bytes_transmitted)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I put the second part of your answer (arg = [] ....) in the end of the program (after all the function calls), right? another question, how can I know that all the requests are sent in the same time? can I print the timestamp?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "I put the second part of your answer (arg = [] ....) in the end of the program (after all the function calls), right?" The second code example is the complete program and I don't know what "all the function calls" refer to. There is only the creation of the `args` list, the creation of the `pool` variable, and one method invocation on that `pool` (`starmap`). There are no explicit function calls. As for your second question, `my_function` can print out a timestamp and they should all be very similar.

Comment: Hello @Booboo my question is where should I put your code, before or after the method 'my_function' invocations  ? ( I should call it **three** times).  I tried to post the code but it's too long. Thanks a lot for you great help.

Comment: My code includes my_function and invokes it. It is complete as is because the args list contains all the arguments required for the three invocations you had. Re-read the answer from the top. I am out now and can’t go into a deeper explanation now.

Comment: I modified the question as it is in my program.  These are the parameters that the function should returned:  `return packets_recieved,packets_transmitted,bytes_recieved,bytes_transmitted`

Comment: I've updated the code. `my_function` now returns a `tuple`:  `packets_recieved,packets_transmitted,bytes_recieved,bytes_transmitted` and I have shown how the main thread processes all the return values.

Comment: I updated the code again as you suggest. Thanks a lot but I think there are some problems in unpacking the `results `. Please help me is the updated code arrangement is right?

Comment: I have to go out now for a while; I will respond in full. when I return. But it is not correct.

Comment: The problem is that your first loop retrieves all N results corresponding to the N arguments in the `args` list but prints nothing. The next 3 loops print the same value (the last result returned) over and over again. See my update.

Comment: Finally works. Thanks a lot for your help. I'm speechless. God bless you.